# Is there a way to cause more NPC quests to be offered?

Tags: starbound

I have built flat straight path over planet surface to allow me to solve *"Bring X to Y"* quests swiftly. However it seems that I picked wrong planet - the quests are starting to be quite rare. I now get max two quests for whole Glitch village located there.

Is there a way to cause them to offer more quests, or to increase population so that there's more potential quest givers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reason I can think of as to why the villagers offer fewer quests is because more and more of them are becoming potential crew members from quest completions.

As for the other half of the last line, there are a couple ways to increase the population:

1. **Buy some colony deeds** from the frog merchant at the outpost. This is definitely the best option if you can afford it since villages already have living spaces constructed (See note 1), you can collect rent from them, they offer quests, and if they become a potential crew member you can hire them or break the deed and replace it to get a new villager.
2. **Wait for the quests where they ask you to go find someone** and bring them back. These people will then live at the village and start offering quests as well.

---

**Note 1:** Normally if you put a deed in where another deed already is it won't work but generated villagers don't have deeds and as such it doesn't matter if you have multiple people in the same house.

Comment: Do villagers that come using the Deed item also initiate the "*Bring missing person*" quests?

Comment: Yes they can certainly do that as well.

Comment: Ok, one last thing. If I decline quest, will that person give me quest I prefer? That would allow me to filter out quests that are simple (which means low reward anyway) and get quests that bring more people in my village.

Comment: I can't check at the moment but after declining a quest they should eventually give you another one. I believe the quests to be entirely random so it may or may not be one you want.